# BeautifulSoup: How to ignore Nested elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to not extract the value inside the span element.

```html
<p class="price">
  US$12.12
  <span class="rrp">US$12.24</span>
</p>
```

This is the code I'm using and it extracts both US$12.12 and US$12.24 inside the span element.

```
for price in (soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'price'})):
    print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contents` to just get the first `element` from your result:

```
print(price.contents[0])
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<p class="price">
  US$12.12
  <span class="rrp">US$12.24</span>
</p>''', "lxml")

for price in (soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'price'})):
    
    print(price.contents[0])
```

#### Output

```
  US$12.12
```